# how to return connection to pool

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource, apache-commons-dbcp

do we need to call any method on dbcp.BasicDataSource or jndi datasource(i'm using jboss) to return the connection after done with it?

Answer (score 31):

Nope, just call `Connection.close()`.  If this connection was obtained from a pooled data source, then it won't actually be closed, it'll just be returned to the pool.